# Is it OK to start a bounty on a question you have answered to promote your answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty

I have seen so many answers to questions that are brilliant, but due to a low number of views they don't have as many upvotes as they should (IMHO).

So, if a user has an answer that they believe deserves more upvotes, is it a good tactic to start a bounty on the question so they can attract more users and in the long-term more upvotes to their answer?

Or it is considered bad behavior, and not a good use of the bounty feature?

Comment: Yes, it's allowed. And to prevent it from being abused, the minimum bounty amount increases each time you do this.

Comment: A cheaper way to increase attention to a question (and thus its answers) is to see if you can edit the title to make it more descriptive, and link the question to duplicates, or where appropriate, other closely related questions.

Comment: If you're doing it for the points you'll be disappointed now and then. Personally I'm here to learn and help. The points are a nice bonus, but I believe it shouldn't be your main objective.

Comment: @Stijn First of all i dont want to start a bounty on any of questions i have answered. And it is not about the points. It is about amazing answers with few upvotes that deserve to get upvotes so that can be distinguished from others and help users in the feature

Comment: Your last comment conflicts with the text in your question: *"more upvotes **to my** answer"*, well, with title itself...

Comment: @brasofilo Yes..I just wanted to phrase my question in first-person and not in third-person so it can be more clarify

Comment: You do know that your minimum spend on questions to which you have posted an answer to is 100, not 50, right?

Comment: See also: [Clever bounty reputation hack](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack).

Comment: Related: [What kind of bounty message is acceptable for promoting your own answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266231/456814).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's a calculated investment. If you think that by investing 100 reputation, you'll earn yourself more than 10 votes, go ahead.

Your bounty might just attract an even better answer.

My $.02: Go for it!

Comment: I think you mean "If you think that by investing 100 reputation, you'll earn yourself more than 10 votes" because your minimum spend on a question to which you have already posted an answer to is 100, not 50 (though this can be gamed by starting the bounty BEFORE posting the answer).

Answer (score 13):

That is perfectly fine. It's not rep-whoring. Call it just a strategy to gain reputation.

I have myself awarded [other answers by other people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998824/automation-add-in-vs-com-add-in) I personally found really helpful with bounties. *You know, sometimes an upvote just does not feel like it's enough. Some answers are exceptionally great and should be highly upvoted and recognized.*

You can award a bounty on a question to promote the answer but if the answer was written by you, you can't receive the bounty.

Bounty is a like a fee you pay for attention but there is not one case I am aware of when you can award yourself a bounty.

Comment: You used to be able to award bounties to your own answer.  You didn't get the rep, but you prevented the bounty from going to any *other* answers.  This feature was removed due to abuses in which people used this as a mechanism for preventing automatically awarded bounties from being awarded to an answer.

Comment: @Servy If you're officially allowed to do this, preventing awarding the bounty to yourself (minus the rep) seems illogical, as it might result in someone not deserving the rep getting it (getting +2 for an answer getting the amount of attention that results from a bounty probably isn't that difficult). Being allowed to award the bounty to yourself **if your answer got the most score during the bounty period** seems to make sense (just putting that out there in case someone thinks that's a good idea).