# Is it OK to start a bounty on the question you asked to gain extra views?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Related (but not duplicate): [Is it OK to start a bounty on a question you have answered to promote your answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254956/is-it-ok-to-start-a-bounty-in-a-question-you-have-answered-to-promote-your-asnwe?cb=1)

If you asked a question and it has acceptable answers; is it OK to start a bounty on it - with intention of awarding to the accepted answer - for the specific purpose of promoting your question, e.g. giving it more views?

Comment: sure, why not??

Comment: This is the exact reason bounties were added in the first place.

Comment: @bluefeet - help never explicitly says yay or nay. Also, typically, "extra views" is discussed on meta in the context of "get a better answer" and not simply "get more views despite existing answer".

Comment: @DVK You can use a bounty to award an "extra" reward to a good answer, plus other reasons -- see [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/) blog about it. One of the reasons is to **draw attention**.

Comment: @bluefeet - thanks. Should be an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's what the bounty is for.  If you read [this blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/) post, you'll notice that a bounty can be started for any of the following reasons:

> **Authoritative reference needed**
> Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

> **Canonical answer required**
> The question is widely applicable to a large audience. A detailed canonical answer is required to address all the concerns.

> **Current answers are outdated**
> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.

> **Draw attention**
> This question has not received enough attention.

> **Improve details**
> The current answers do not contain enough detail.

> **Reward existing answer**
> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

You'll notice that **Draw Attention** is one of the options. Starting a bounty will typically draw more views to it, but if you use this reason it will explain why you started it.