# What kind of bounty message is acceptable for promoting your own answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty

According to [Is it OK to start a bounty on a question you have answered to promote your answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254956/is-it-ok-to-start-a-bounty-on-a-question-you-have-answered-to-promote-your-answe/254985#254985), it's generally considered OK to promote your answer on a question by adding a bounty to the question.

However, I was wondering what the most appropriate way to do this is? In particular, **what kind of bounty message is acceptable for promoting your own answer?** We often discourage asking other users for upvotes...and yet that's exactly what we're asking for when we try to promote our own answers with bounties.

### The direct approach?

Do people think that it's OK to directly point out your answer in a bounty message? For example, using the **Reward existing answer** or **Draw attention** bounty reasons:

> This bounty is for promoting my own answer `<link to answer>`! Look at how good it is!

### The indirect approach?

If directly pointing out your own answer in a bounty message to promote it is not considered ok, then how do you go about promoting it indirectly? Do you have to resort to simply saying:

> Please review the answers to this question, and upvote anything you find correct and useful.

?

The problem with promoting your answer indirectly like this is if there are already a lot of competing answers on the question, and they're all more highly upvoted than yours because your answer is newer, people won't necessarily bother to look for your answer and consider upvoting it, so you'd end up just wasting your time (and reputation points) by trying to promote your answer this way.

Comment: You might want to add motivation for adding a new answer: Like [Old question, new technology, new answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258363/old-question-new-technology-new-answer), an overlooked approach, an answer avoiding/highlighting all the pits the others fell into / avoided without mention... Because often, the existig answers are more than sufficient.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm sorry, I don't understand, can you clarify please?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I meant, beside it being useful for this question to mention why one should consider adding another answer respective only editing/commenting an existing one, that mentioning that motivation in the bounty comment might be a good idea.

Comment: I think directly promoting your own answer is OK as long as you do it tastefully. Personally, I'd rather just use [comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202109/flagging-look-at-my-answer-pls-comments/202111#202111), but the disadvantage of comments is that only those who will be notified of the comments will see them immediately, and anyone else who might happen to come across the question.

Comment: @BoltClock but how do you "tastefully" promote your answer? That's what I'm trying to figure out. What kind of message is "tasteful"?

Comment: Definitely not the one you have suggested. I would suggest something like the comment I linked to.

Comment: @BoltClock thank you, the example in the linked answer was very helpful.

Comment: @VotetoClose this is why people need to leave answers so that everyone can vote on them `:P`

Answer (score 5):

When the meta question was asked about drawing attention to your answer so that it might receive more upvotes than your bounty costs, the consensus was that it was your bounty to lose, if you so choose; it is your gamble to take.

That does not necessarily make it a good use of bounties, however.  It only means that you roll the dice and take your chances, without concerns about breaking the rules (or hope for getting your bounty refunded if it doesn't work out).

As you've already observed, a more specific bounty message works better than a less specific one.  Beyond that, your question seems to boil down to asking the community for better message copy, and since I'm not a salesman...

Comment: It's "breaking the rules" that I'm mostly concerned about with regards to message copy. So what you're essentially saying is that there are no official rules for this, and what kind of message is acceptable to people is primarily opinion-based?

Comment: AFAIK you can put anything you want into bounty messages, subject to the usual standards of professionalism.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it all now. So because users are basically free to vote however they want (as long as they don't repeatedly target a specific user), no matter what kind of bounty message you use, some users may just decide to downvote the post you're promoting anyways, just because they disagree that it's ok to promote your own answer with a bounty?