# Can I set a bounty to bring attention to a question I gave an answer to?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I recently found an interesting question asking for a time-efficient algorithm for some problem. I gave an answer containing two approaches. Someone suggested that an answer to an old related question might also be applicable. So the OP created a Wiki answer to benchmark those three approaches.

I think the question has not received enough attention, and I'd like to offer a bounty on it, to see if someone can come up with a better approach.

However, since I'm the only one who has given a proper answer, perhaps it could be interpreted that I'm wickedly offering a bounty to reward my own answer. I imagine the system has some means to prevent that from happening. If that's the case, my intent could never be seen as wicked.

So, my questions:

1. Does the system have a means that will prevent me from rewarding my own answer? (To be clear: I *don't* want to do that, but I want people to know that I *couldn't* do it even if I wanted to.)
2. Is it acceptable / good practice for me to set a bounty to bring more attention to that question? Are there any objections to that?

Comment: [Setting a bounty to draw attention to your own answer is acceptable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254956/is-it-ok-to-start-a-bounty-on-a-question-you-have-answered-to-promote-your-answe/254985#254985) anyway, so don't worry about it.

Comment: This brings to bear the notion of whether we should be able to award bounties for great questions. I think the answer should be yes.

Comment: @TylerH I've sometimes felt that need to

Comment: Luis, you have 42K rep, I am pretty sure that in your case it wont be seen as wicked, as you don't "need it".

Comment: @AnderBiguri That's a good argument, yes. But I just wanted to make sure. It's the first bounty I set, and I wasn't sure about the policy

Comment: @Krumia Thanks for the edit! And nice avatar :-)

Comment: Make sure you include a link to the question in the question you ask about the validity of this approach on MSE to ensure you get that bit more attention and a few more votes as well ;)

Comment: @SamHolder Yeah, the meta "effect"... but in this case it would have looked a bit like cheating! :-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can not award your own answer the bounty. You could in the past, though you still wouldn't get the rep. This was changed in 2011, according to a [post on MSE by Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97802/276203):

> Now that accepting an answer and awarding the bounty are 2 distinct actions - possibly from different users as well, **you can no longer award the bounty to your own answer**.

As for whether or not it is acceptable - by all means, go ahead. That is the whole point of a bounty; to get the question more attention. It'll certainly help with getting more answers with better approaches to solving the problem.

You should note, however, that since you answered the question already, the minimum bounty is raised. From the [Bounty help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

Comment: Thanks This pretty much clarifies the whole thing. I'll wait for a while to see if there any other answers before accepting this one or some other

Comment: Why can't you claim back your own Bounty? On my old account, a while ago, I wrote a question that remained unanswered for weeks. I did plenty of research both before and after writing the question. I offered a 500 rep bounty and after I started the bounty I still had no answers come in for a week. After the week had passed, I eventually managed to solve my own problem. So I wrote and accepted my own answer. The bounty was not awarded to me or anybody else. So basically, it was a waste of reputation. Why? Why should things go to waste?

Comment: It feels like we are being punished in a way, for contributing to the community, simply because others do not want, or are not able to post an answer. Personally, I do not care. But it does seem rather illogical.

Comment: @Jase This is because the bounty isn't there just to reward the answerer. As the question-asker, you pay the bounty fee for the added attention of having the question be on the "featured" page and get more hits/views. Nothing is going to waste - you did get those two things in exchange for the reputation you gave up. It's unfortunate that nobody knew the answer, but I'm happy that you found it yourself.

Answer (score 22):

In regard to #1:

> #### Can I award a bounty to my own answer?
>
> No. This used to be possible, but it has been disabled. The user would not get the reputation back, and the bounty will be displayed as +0, “this answer has been awarded bounty worth 0 reputation”.

<sub>(From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work))</sub>

So, yes, the system has a way of preventing you from awarding yourself for your own answer (which, even if you could, would just result in a net 0 gain because you would be giving yourself back the reputation you put up in the form of a bounty).

However, you will still get the attention that a bounty brings, including the blue marker on the question (which results in substantially increased attention for the question) and placement in the ["featured" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured). This extra attention usually results in a few extra upvotes that you wouldn't have had otherwise.

If you want to be really clear of your intentions with the bounty, you can put your reasoning in the bounty remark.

For #2, it is most definitely acceptable to set a bounty to bring attention to a question; *that's what bounties are for*. If someone objects, then they don't understand the concept of a bounty. In fact, it's in the definition:

> If you’ve asked a good question, edited it with status and progress updates, and still are not receiving answers, **you can draw attention to your question** by placing a bounty on it.

<sub>(From [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty))</sub>

(It doesn't matter whether it's actually *your* question.)

Comment: Thanks. That's more or less what I thought, but I just wanted to make sure my bounty would not be misintepreted :-)

Comment: I would have liked to accept both answers :-) as either of them clarifies the issue. I've accepted the other answer because it was posted a little earlier