# The answer I'm writing exceeds the 30k maximum character limit; what should I do?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, character-limit

I've written a very long answer, with a *lot* of details - Now, I want to add even more, but, when I pasted the latest version of my answer into the edit box, it told me that answers are not allowed to be longer than 30k characters:

> [image: Screenshot]

Some details about my answer:

- It's a list of things that can be done in order prevent or deter something (website scraping).
- There's very little code, and most of the text isn't code.

Some possibilites I've come up with:

1. Post a longer version of my answer somewhere else, and link to it - however this would mean more effort to maintain two different versions, and I don't really like this idea.
2. Try to make it fit into 30k characters - this would be quite some effort, and not a really a long-term solution, as I will inevitably want to add to it.
3. Post it somewhere else (for example, a blog), and delete it from Stack Overflow - I don't really like this solution, since I love Stack Overflow, I don't have a blog, and I've got a feeling that nobody will ever see it and benefit from it. (And I wouldn't get reputation points for it ;-))
4. Just leave it as is - However I don't really like the idea leaving it as is when I could improve it (in fact, I already *have* improved it).
5. Just continue in a second post.

So, what should I do? Is this kind of answer even appropriate for Stack Overflow?

This is the answer: *[How do I prevent site scraping?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34828465/4428462)*

(I've also put the latest version [on GitHub](https://github.com/JonasCz/How-To-Prevent-Scraping), which is around 40k characters).

**As a bit of an update:** I've now done what Joe and others have suggested: I've trimmed down the answer, removed a lot of fluff and some of the less important points, and I've added a link to the GitHub page with the more complete version. Thank you all for your input and opinion, and I now know a lot more about Stack Overflow than I did before :-)

Comment: Maybe this is the epitome of "too broad" - "good answers would be too long"?

Comment: @Makoto, That's what I was thinking - So not suitable for SO ?

Comment: The question itself is too long to capture here, so that's what my gut is telling me.  Perhaps if it were broken out into more distinct and digestible pieces, it *could* be acceptable...

Comment: 30k characters is a lot of text.  That's about 6k words, or roughly 12 pages of double-spaced text.

Comment: There are a few cases where an answer is split into multiple separate posts just to fit all the minute detail in. But that's rarely appropriate.

Comment: 30k characters is too long for an answer in my book, full stop.

Comment: Ive just read your answer, its good but there is a LOT of blurb. I'm going to go out on a limb and say I think you could keep the useful content, remove the blurb and *easily* fit in the 30K limit

Comment: I think it is a good reference answer; however I find the longer one on GitHub not so good, as it has become repetitious and not so concise and directed. In this case the word limit has helped the focus.

Comment: Like Brian said, the GitHub version repeats a good deal, especially the end part.

Comment: WOW!  I would not dare - for sure the question would be deleted just before I posted my humongous, detailed answer:(

Comment: @MartinJames, You could always post your answer on your blog then if you can't post it on SO :-)

Comment: 30000 characters are many a times insufficient, especially when a full exception stack-trace (which is required) thrown from a layered enterprise application like Java EE is to be included in the question / answer body.

Comment: That would actually make a decent book, then you could sell it and make real money off of it instead of fake internet points.

Comment: ^ 44 pages in MS Word...

Comment: @Tiny, I actually often find it annoying when there's huge amounts of code / logs / traces  in the question itself - I guess the character limit was specifically implemented to reduce that kind of thing. I think that the best way to include such things in a question is to include what seems / is relevant in the question, and the rest as a linked gist / pastebin - although others may disagree with me.

Comment: Somehow I got that ping instead of the other @Tiny, that was confusing.

Comment: @JonasCz you should _never_ create two posts/answers on StackOverflow. This disrupts the possibility of a "best" answer, as then both of your answers would be best.

Comment: @onebree: [An example of this phenomenon](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/212307/microchip-pic18f-can-message-reception-problem/212313#212313) on another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @onebree You do, if you have much to say and the topic is quite diverse. See this example from [security.se]. D.W. posted **9** answers and the OP posted another **4**. [Lessons learned and misconceptions regarding encryption and cryptology](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/2202/45523)

Comment: @onebree You might want to qualify that. Posting multiple answers is fine if they're all distinct answers; posting one answer as a continuation of another answer just to get around the length limit is not okay.

Comment: "I have made this longer than usual because I have not had time to make it shorter." — *Blaise Pascal*; "If a sentence does not illuminate your subject in some new and useful way, scratch it out" — *Kurt Vonnegut, Jr.* IEEE Transactions on Professional Communication.

Comment: The answer / comment to that question is a simple "no it is not possible" :-). Also your note about "Use JavaScript + Ajax to load your content" is not a solution because even when a scraper doesn't support javascript it's still just http requests.

Comment: @onebree if you have two different ways to attack a problem, they should be two separate answers.

Comment: Its set of rules in Stack Overflow...  So simply write (split into 2/3.. Continue tag )another answer

Comment: I never imagined that anybody would ever hit the limit. I always knew about it, but I've always ignored it.

Comment: @UiDesigner Incomplete answers deserve downvotes. Also, can you imagine how confusing that would be if the answers were not in order? Users can change their sorting preferences, you know.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot exactly, I agree. Visitors will likely only read the top-voted (default-sort) or accepted answer, which could be part 2/3. If your answer is a new approach, then I still think you should put it in ONE answer, using markdown headings to differentiate.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Re that Electronics.SE example: That's actually kind of horrible IMO - The "addition" is actually accepted and pinned to the top, thus fragmenting the answer and requiring extra effort to understand. Also, it's the huge amount of code which is causing that answer to go over the length limit, an that's a different problem really. I recently answered a similar question here with a link to a specific class in my OSS project which did exactly what the OP wanted, plus a description of how I implemented it - I think this is a lot nicer than dumping a 1k line class into an answer.

Comment: @PeeHa, Yes, I completely agree that it can't be prevented, but it can be made harder. If I use plain HTML, someone only needs to download the HTML, run a regex on it, and that's it. However, JS + Ajax needs to be figured out, endpoints need to be discovered, and obfuscation (if used) reverse engineered. Just look at the number of "I want to scrape this website but it uses js, help !" questions in various tags. Oh, and let's try to keep the comments here on-topic - if you have comments about my answer _you can comment on my answer_.

Comment: tl;dr (8 more to go...)

Comment: I think this question has gotten too many comments! Stackoverflow should add a limit :P! Ah yes, and per the question: I think you should write a BOOK instead of Stack Overflow answer :P. Upvote this, if you agree.

Comment: @Bart Or upvote TinyGiant's comment which says exactly the same thing.

Comment: The question was "How can I prevent screen scraping? Is it even possible?", your answer should probably be "Yes, here's the best possible ways how...". It really doesn't have to be as involved as you've made it. But as others have mentioned, you do seem very passionate about the subject and that's awesome so maybe write a blog post and add it as a linked addendum?

Comment: @MattK, That's pretty much what I've done - just that instead of a blog post, I've used a GitHub page (GitHub even has issues and pull requests, whereas a blog doesn't, and I've already gotten the first PR..), and linked to that. I actually quite like that. (I've also tried to trim down my answer here on SO a bit, but I'm finding that quite hard.)

Comment: @Jamiec, I've edited the answer and cut out _a lot_ of the fluff. If you like, check it out and I'd love to hear what you think.

Comment: @JonasCz - Looks good. Not sure if you have fitted everything you wanted to within the limit but in any case thats a really top quality answer to a very broad question.

Comment: @JonasCz I think you've just outed yourself as [one of those people](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/11/03/guys-who-overdo-it-on-stackoverflow/) ;)

Comment: Less is more ...

Comment: @JonasCz The question is closed as too broad now.

Comment: Hi @JonasCz ... your level-headness about this is ........ ***incredible***.  I'd be on here laughing my ass off and asking what 95 year-old set a post size limit to ................ *WAIT FOR IT* ....... a whole 30k.  So funny!  30k!

Comment: PS thanks for the great answer - obviously, difficult questions require longer answers than a sentence.

Comment: @JoeBlow: There is a sizeable set of reasonable post sizes between "one sentence" and "an 30,000 character essay".

Comment: just for reference, the 30k Character limit is network wide (AFAIK), **except** on Code Review, where the limit is 65k and a bit, because both questions and answers there can be very extensive

Comment: Stop at 30k chars, and then continue writing the rest in thirteen 600-char comments.

Comment: Somehow I’m missing the option to **compress** your answer and then post a Base64-encoded dump of it.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Answers that are 30k characters long are too long for this site. The site doesn't handle them well - you have to scroll through the *entire* answer to get to anything below it, and that's *really long*.  Stack Overflow also doesn't aim for questions/answers that *require* 30k character answers - short, reasonably well-tailored questions/answers are the aim.

Feeling that a question needs an answer of 30k+ characters tells me one of two things. Either the question is too broad in scope, or the answer is too broad in scope for the question.

In your case, it's a bit of both I think: the question asked is *very* broad; but you also are writing a *very* broad answer which attempts to answer everything possible related to the question. That's not necessarily a *bad* thing, per se, but for a question that's already this broad, it means you have too large of an answer for this site.

So, what should you do?

### Write a blog post

It sounds like you want to share a lot of information on this topic.  Great! Write a blog post with all of the information you have there.  Then, *summarize* it in a Stack Overflow answer, and link to the post for more information. If the answer, *by itself*, is a good answer, then this is perfect: you have the necessary information in the answer, *plus* more information in the post.

### Narrow your answer's scope

Instead of trying to answer all possible things remotely related to the question, pick a narrower scope. You don't have to give a full background and comprehensive list of things to look at; you can focus on the main points. What is *one* major approach? Or a couple?

### Limit the detail in your answer

If you do want to provide a 'breadth' answer, then remove some of the fine details. Your section headers look like they're pretty descriptive and actionable; maybe they don't need all that text under them. This isn't always as good of an answer as a narrower but deeper answer, but when accompanying a bunch of other answers (as yours is) sometimes it's a better contribution overall.

Comment: This looks good - Less detail in the answer itself, with a more detailed version elsewhere, and a link to it in the answer. Looks like that's what I will probably do. Since I don't have a blog (yet) I might as well stick with keeping it on GitHub.

Comment: Another possibility which comes up pretty rarely: if there are multiple divergent answers bundled into a single answer it would be appropriate to answer the question multiple times. I don't feel that multiple answers is appropriate in this specific case, but I think it's worth at least mentioning with a disclaimer.

Comment: This answer is 2000 chars. His is 15x longer than this!

Comment: @JonasCz it's fairly trivial to set up GitHub and GitHub pages for a static blog / HTML (or using a blog engine like Jekyll)

Comment: @JonasCz It may be a better idea to use github gists, as your current repo only holds one file. If you have not done so already, please edit your answer. Instead of detailing what each heading means, scrap all that and just put the headings into a list. Although not the same format, [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242006/how-to-enable-sorttable-js-on-rails4-with-turbolinks/30507463#30507463) pointed to a LONG gist, with too much code for SO Q&A. And if you ARE interested in a blog, maybe put your answer in multiple posts. This is a great starter entry/series :-)

Comment: @onebree, GH gists don't have issues or pull requests (Unlikely that i'll need those, but who knows), and I might add more files to that repo (code snippets, images, license...) But yes, otherwise that's an interesting idea, although I generally like to have things on SO itself instead of a short explanation and a link for more.

Comment: @usr 18.5x even (37321 characters). The limit is 15 times this answer.

Comment: `I don't have a blog` Perhaps look for a popular blogger that writes about a related topic and ask if you could contribute a guest post.

Comment: Why isn't there a Stack Overflow blog, I wonder?  Other SE sites have them.

Comment: @Joe because it became "the Stack Overflow©" blog

Comment: The comment "Answers that are 30k characters long are too long for this site." may be true but seems to draw a bit of an arbitrary line. Who came up with 30k? What about 29k? Etc..

Comment: @Tommy Jeff, most likely. And what's wrong with arbitrary?  Got to draw it somewhere.

Comment: @Joe: *'Why isn't there a Stack Overflow blog, I wonder?'* Ironically, according to this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/ ,SO *is* also the blog..

Comment: @Joe the problem with arbitrary is that it allows other people with equal and arbitrary opinions to say "the limit should be 40K", like the OP, and your only response is "my opinion is better than yours".

Comment: That answer is way too long for a blog too. Better with multiple blog posts, part 1, part 2....

Comment: @Tommy Everyone can have opinion but think of the alternative: no limits at all. It doesn't sound very viable option IMHO. The guy who pays the bills, wears the biggest hat or is in charge for some other reason, has only two options: to limit or not to limit. After that everything is arbitrary. (Also technical limit is to a certain point arbitrary: `int` vs. `bigint`, `text` vs. `mediumtext` etc.) If you care for your product/platform, you end up limiting a lot of things or the moderators would quite possibly burn out very quickly...

Answer (score 80):

This is exactly what closing a question as "Too Broad" tries to prevent. This question and your answer simply are not suitable for the Stack Overflow Q&A format.

As suggested, you could write a blog post (or multiple) and make your answer in list form and link to that blog, but that won't take away that the *question* is too broad. Its answers are a collection of "tips and tricks" that may or may not be true, and may or may not work.

Besides that, the definitive answer to *"How can I prevent scraping of my website?"*, is missing, namely *"Given a determined enough scraper, you can't"*.

Comment: Most likely that last line was beyond the 30K limit.

Answer (score 10):

The fact that you needed so many words to even attempt to answer the question should have been your first clue that maybe, *just maybe*, you shouldn't be trying to answer it at all.

Apart from the fact that this question is the very definition of the "too broad" close reason, it's also **over half a decade old**. Why you felt the need to answer an off-topic, ancient question is beyond me. Why you felt the need to answer such a question with **over thirty thousand characters** is... well, I thought *I* was unnecessarily verbose. :p

Answering an overly broad question with an overly broad answer **is not helping**. Sticking a bounty on the question to prevent it from being closed - as it should be - makes it seem that you're trying to keep the question open purely so your answer can get some screen time. (This is a harsh and perhaps unfair viewpoint, but I have relatively little information to go on, so please correct me if this is an invalid assumption on my part.)

As such, I've raised a moderator flag requesting the question to be closed. If that amounts to nothing, I will cast a close vote when the bounty(ies) expire.

Your answer, in its current form, is a great fit for a blog post or GitHub, but not for Stack Overflow, and not on that question.

Comment: As, I said, I've learned a lot about SO - and I won't post an answer like this again. I answered this question because the other answers where incomplete and outdated, and I felt _I could contribute something good_, something better than my usual FGITW answers. With the bounty - You're partially right, but the intention wasn't really to "get my answer some scree time" - and the intention most certainly wasn't to prevent closure. Rather I started the bounty after my answer sat there at the _very end of the page_ for weeks, and it seemed nobody would ever see it and benefit from it.

Comment: As a note: The bounty has actually resulted in two other new, fairly high quality answers, so even though the question is off-topic, I think this is still a benefit. (oh, and finally: a moderator closing the question would require a refund of the bounty (?), which is probably not such a good thing (?))

Comment: @JonasCz What you're saying is that you wrote your very long answer and nobody read it, so you put a bounty on the question to get people to read your answer. Regardless of the reason, that's still self-promotion - bounties are for askers, or people who find a question that they think is neglected... But I'm not going to harp on about this because I think you understand the site better now, and because you're actually contributing good content. In future, however, please ensure you reserve that good content for good questions! :)

Comment: @IanKemp I want to point something out: [It has been discussed on Meta before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254956/), that using bounties to promote your own answer is _not against the rules_ since 1) it could result in more, better answers by other users 2) you can't reward yourself anyway and 3) you have to pay double the minimum if you start a bounty on a question you already answered, so if you don't get 10 upvotes after posting the bounty, you're out rep anyway. (Or if you get downvotes rather than upvotes.) See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286103/

Comment: As to the close vote - It got closed, 5 people thought it should he reopened, so it got reopened, but hey, now I was able to spend one of my first close votes after reaching 3k on it :-)

Answer (score 9):

"my answer: It's a list of things"

You may have tried to cram multiple answers in a single answer. While not generally encouraged* , you are certainly allowed to post multiple answers, and certainly if each answer highlights the conditions in which it's appropriate.

*) People new to this site occasionally add an answer when trying to "reply" to another answer. That's bad enough, but if the answerer replies with yet another answer the Q&A format breaks down into unintended dialogue. Another reason is to prevent reposting an improved answer as a second answer, instead of just editing the original answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can split this big answer into separate parts (an answer per solution) and refer to related answers by hyperlinks if it is nessesary.

The other way is to shrink the length by the formatting. Some examples:

- If you have a lot of code formatted by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> you are spending 4 chars per line, but if you just wrap the code into `<pre><code>`...`</code></pre>` you'll spent only 24 chars for the whole block.
- Now you can format code even shorter - use ```` ``` ```` on separate lines at the beginning and ending - just 8 chars for the whole block.
- In the code you can replace spaces by tabs.
- You don't need code marking (4 spaces indentation or `<pre><code>`) inside of the snippets, but the system inserts the code with 4 spaces like the usual code.
- In the answer you can use 2 spaces at the end of the line instead of `<br>`.
- You can use inline hyperlinks without explicit protocol: `[Google](//google.com)`: [Google](//google.com)
- For the links to other questions or answers you don't need to write the site and can drop the title: `[This question](/questions/316012)`: [This question](/questions/316012).
  Or even shorter: `[This question](/q/316012)`: [This question](/q/316012).
- You can skip repeating of the marker for the multiline quote inside one paragraph.

I'm sure a lot of formatting tricks can be applied.

Comment: The formatting tips are great, thanks ! That would also mean less typing. I disagree about spiltting it up though, as then it would not be one coherent piece anymore, the order would not be right (due to voting andtye default sort order), and other reasons I can't really think of right now.

Comment: @JonasCz, I ment, that if you have 4 ways to solve the problem, you can post each solution in separate answer, not just to split the answer into parts.

Comment: I get you, the thing is that here, I've got 20 ways to solve the problem..

Comment: @JonasCz, what about splitting into cattegories? Like "Ways acceptable if ... are, but for the other cases see <link to the other answer>." But yep, the can be cases where splitting is not a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this would fit better on Stack Overflow if you broke up the question into multiple, more specific questions, and then posted the specific parts of your answer to each of those questions.

It would solve the issue of the 30k limit while keeping all the content on Stack Overflow, and in a way that would benefit users who are only interested in some part of the answer. You could cross-link the questions/answers if it makes sense.

Comment: For any other (compound) question, this would be the proper solution. For that specific question: it would only be more questions to close as "*waaay* too broad".

Answer (score 4):

I reviewed the GitHub version of your answer. I would say you haven't made a serious effort to edit it for length.

- The first four paragraphs are just blather and can be deleted without loss.
- There is no functional difference between bullet points 2 and 3, only a difference in how they are constructed. (This also contradicts the prior claim that 'each works differently'.)
- Don't put punctuation in headings, and don't put spaces before question marks, or around / when used to express alternation.
- You don't need both the 'General' heading *and* the short paragraph that follows it.
- Lots of blather, such as 'specifically, some ideas' where only the first word is necessary; another nearby example is 'it is a good idea to ...', which is entirely redundant. Ditto '[some] indicators ... [include]', where the words in brackets are redundant. Ditto 'in order to ... [, you should]:'.
- You have at least two separate sections about Captcha. Combine them.

That's as far as I got, but it is clear there is considerable room for improvement. I would get someone else to look at it for you and blue-pencil it ruthlessly.

Comment: Thanks for your input ! In fact, I've already shortened the version here on Stack Overflow, and done most of the things you mentioned. In fact, I haven't edited the GitHub one for length at all yet., I agree that there's lots of room for improvement, andthat it's also a good idea for someone else to look at it.

Answer (score 3):

This is something that just popped to my mind, but this kind of questions, ”How do I do X”, kind of feel more like requesting a tutorial, so this kind of questions more of belongs to, in my mind, to the documentation side.

I don’t know if the upcoming documentation SE actually allows this kind of vague, not project related topics, but quite often there is things that is not obvious, where information where the thing can be done scattered all around, incomplete and/or obsolete, so I see value in long answers explaining how the thing is supposed to be done, while maybe out of scope on Stack Overflow, maybe better suited to more documentation related site. I mean, Stack Overflow is meant to be used for simple, specific questions, rather than as a service that gives howtos about how a thing can be done, what needs to be taken in consideration and other generic usage notes.

The documentation site would contain generic instruction about how this thing should be used, and Stack Overflow would cover specific problems, like, why I couldn’t do the crawler in this way if I want to achieve this thing in order to produce that, which may be too unrelevant case to include in the main documentation.