# How to improve the visibility of my answer especially in posts that have lots of other answers?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

We have bounties for making our questions featured, but there are hardly any effective mechanisms or tools to improve the visibility of the answers, especially in cases where the question already has too many answers or replies and there is pagination to navigate across answers.

The use case I am referring to is mostly happening on Meta where the new announcement or suggestion seeking posts get so many of replies from the waking part of the world immediately; that when the turn comes for the people of other side of the world, they either gets unnoticed or less viewed.

I had posted [minor feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369753/2828434) for the post [“Ask a question” wizard prototype](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369682/2828434) and [another](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358250/2828434) on the *[What can we put in a question template to help people ask better questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357951/2828434)* question, which I think adds genuine suggestion and feedback and I really want it to go to officials at SO. But I am afraid it will go unnoticed. I know there are filters to sort the answers (Active, Votes, etc.), but it still doesn't quite serve the purpose.

One method I found in many posts was that answerers add their answer's links in the comment with an intriguing comment line - clicking on the link directly open their answer. But I don't think it to be reliable because it might get cleaned up.

From the comment of @Lundin, *"For the kind of questions like "please give us feedback about feature x", the SO crew will likely dig through every single answer. At least that's been the case in the past. You might note "status-x" tags popping up in some of the answers in those threads."* Right, is it possible that the asker or OP (only if there are many answers = 10+ or more), get to mark each answer he/she reads as "Status-Read" so that at least the responder knows that the answer has been read, even if it isn't being reviewed, planned, rejected, or completed currently?

Comment: maybe if you write them in bold, they are more visible

Comment: @drunkensquirrel surely, you jest.

Comment: **A visible comment** :p

Comment: @yivi ahah yes,logical :D

Comment: Ya certainly, that can be the case. But can't we have any way to determine answer views (stats/reach) just as we have question view numbers if at all?

Comment: It would be great if you could find a way to make your answers more visible, then we could all use it all the time.

Comment: So, you think your answers are more important than the other answers? Sounds elitist :).

Comment: Even someone with 8 golden batches and 100K reputation can have it wrong :)

Comment: For the kind of questions like "please give us feedback about feature x", the SO crew will likely dig through every single answer. At least that's been the case in the past. You might note "status-x" tags popping up in some of the answers in those threads.

Comment: As for how to draw attention to the post, simply include cute cat pictures.

Comment: About your edit: I tend to despise users that comment all other answers with a link to their (often not better) answer, which does not play in their favor. Also don't rely only in votes for post quality, an answer can be upvoted many times before a better new one is added, people are weird, etc. My solution: red free hand circles.. it attracts the eye :P

Comment: @Kaddath Cute cat pictures with red free hand circles. And hand-drawn red text saying "cat". We're on to something here.

Comment: @Kaddath Comments suggesting looking at an answer on an answer that is genuinely related I can accept, but the carpet bomb "please look at my better answer here" borders on spam/abuse IMO.

Comment: It isn't any different on SO itself; as much as SO wants to be global, your questions being noticed and answered and your answers being noticed and upvoted are very timezone-dependent. (At least that's my impression; maybe there's data about this?)

Comment: Share it on reddit.

Comment: I always filter on active as opposed to votes or oldest, I'm sure others do to.

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ya

Comment: Not all browsers support the `<BLINK>` tag. What you want to do is _also_ use the `<MARQUEE>` tag. For browsers that support both, getting your code to look good when it's both moving around and blinking can be hard, but if you have at least 5 different colors or at least 3 fonts, that usually helps.

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery?

Answer (score 12):

I know of a few ways you can make your answer visible to more people. I am not necessarily recommend you do any of these, but will share them for information's sake:

- Post a bounty drawing attention to the question. True, this may be more costly than you want, but people will come to the question, and will likely see your answer.
- Edit your answer. This will put at the top of the list of answers when sorted by "active". It will also bump the question, and when people see the question with the link off to the right saying "edited X minutes ago by Karan Desai" they can click that link to go straight to your answer. This should only be done when you have something substantive to add. Don't just edit your answer willy nilly; that's abuse.
- Post a comment under other answers or the question if relevant - e.g. "this answer fails to accomplish X, see [my answer] for a way to handle that. This is not really recommended, especially as a comment under the question, because it just smacks of advertising yourself, and comments that do this are likely to get deleted swiftly with prejudice.
- Share an answer via Twitter or other social media network using the "Share" link below every post. Alternatively you could post it in a chatroom (if the chatroom's rules allow) or on Reddit if there's a particularly relevant subreddit/discussion.
- And of course, the ever-present "focus on quality" approach - higher-quality answers tend to gather more upvotes, and tend to rise to the top of the pile when sorted by votes.

Comment: All of these except the last one are abhorrent behaviors that clutter the site with nonsense.

Comment: @jpmc26 None of these except the comment one add any kind of 'clutter' to the site. The 4th one isn't even an action to take *on this site*. Did you even read the answer?

Comment: Bounties that are not intended to draw new answers or reward existing ones are nonsense and an abuse of the system. Useless edits are nonsense that clutter the activity lists, *including the one you're telling the user to abuse*. Comments are for improving the post. Linking an answer doesn't help that, so you should only be pointing out the problem. Posting on Twitter isn't clutter, I guess, but it's not attracting people who actually need or will use the answer, just the poster's friends. As such, the votes hold far less meaning than they should. Why are you promoting abusive use of the site?

Comment: @jpmc26 I see, so you didn't read the answer. Or you are intentionally *mis*reading it. 1. The bounty option I recommended was to draw attention to the question. It's perfectly fine to post a bounty to a question to get more answers even if all you really want is more people to come looking at yours. You *can't* award yourself a bounty or get that rep back so it's not really a case of abuse. 2. I don't tell the user to abuse any edit, in fact I say specifically *not* to abuse the edit function. Is today opposite day? 3. I see you don't know how Twitter works (tip: see hashtags and mentions)

Comment: @jpmc26 Regarding your bounty concerns, [this has come up before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286103/can-i-set-a-bounty-to-bring-attention-to-a-question-i-gave-an-answer-to) and [it's perfectly acceptable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234526/is-it-ok-to-make-a-bounty-to-draw-attention-to-my-answer) to bounty a question to promote your answer. Aka, _not an abuse of the system._

Comment: @Kendra I don't care what that Q/A says. Adding a bounty for a question that doesn't *need* new answers is going to waste the time of people looking through bountied questions. They'll waste the time required to read and understand the question only to likely find there's nothing to add.

Comment: @jpmc26 If you don't care whether or not an action _is a perfectly valid use of the site_ or not, even when it's come up multiple times (those are not the only posts about it) and been determined to be fine _by the community,_ then nothing anyone says is going to convince you what is and is not an abuse of the site. But do be prepared to have people point out that what you perceive as an abuse in this case is not considered so by the community, per various meta posts.

Comment: @Kendra There's no official guidance on the matter. That's just the opinion of a couple random users. The top answer even says they're not sure.

Comment: @jpmc I'm fairly certain there is a bounty reason along the lines of "this question has an excellent answer that deserves more attention". There's nothing saying that answer can't be owned by the person starting the bounty. If someone feels that the person starting the bounty has wasted their time with an answer that is in-fact not excellent then it is within their purview to downvote said answer for a lack of usefulness. It is _not_ an abuse of the system to do any of this.

Comment: @TylerH Bounties are to reward an answerer for going above/beyond to solve the question's problem, whether that's by paying special attention to it or having an excellent answer. It's not okay to clutter the bounty list with questions where they can't spend that effort. Whether you make substantive edits should be independent of the desire to promote your answer. The fact you *mention it as a strategy for self promotion* is inherently problematic. Twitter results don't come up in Google for programming problems, so it's not drawing people who actually need the solution.

Comment: @jpmc26 Bounties are also to draw attention to a question in general. It's not just to reward an existing answer. As for the rest, I and others have already explained how you're wrong so I won't spend time on rehashing that.

Comment: @TylerH If bounties were for arbitrary "drawing attention to questions" as opposed to getting/rewarding answers on those questions, you'd be able to award them to the question directly, not just the answers. You also wouldn't have to select a reason *about the answers* when starting one.

Comment: @jpmc26 From the [page on bounties as a privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties): `A bounty is a reputation reward you can put on a question to get it more attention for exactly one week.` The "it" there refers to the question itself. If you disagree with this you should probably post a separate meta question seeking clarification or a verbiage change.

Comment: @TylerH It also says, "When should I place a bounty?" and the answer begins, "In order to get good answers..." The only attention it's talking about is getting answers. In fact, that section actively *discourages* posting bounties in the first place and gives alternatives around improving the question.

Comment: @jpmc26 It is not super clear but that paragraph is written in the context of posting a bounty on your own question only. It doesn't make sense when read from the perspective of posting a bounty on someone else's question, e.g. "posting status updates to the question", etc.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, it does: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325860/1394393 Although you might put them in an answer rather than the question if you didn't author the question. Either way, there would still be an open problem.

Comment: @jpmc26 I don't see how that link helps support your argument that the paragraph can make sense in the context of posting a bounty on someone else's question. Or how it's related to bounties at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173842/discussion-between-jpmc26-and-tylerh).

Answer (score -1):

You don't. You trust the community to see your answer and vote or respond appropriately. Sometimes it takes time. If it's a good answer, it'll usually end up near the top eventually. If it doesn't, it wasn't that great, at least in readers' opinion.

This has been my own personal experience; it is not speculative. Focus on quality if you want your answers to get attention.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, [cats with freehand arrows](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370110/how-to-improve-the-visibility-of-my-answer-especially-in-posts-that-has-lots-of#comment603789_370110).

Comment: Note that the two example questions the asker mentioned already have multiple _pages_ of answers. I think this makes it much more unlikely that even high quality answers will get much attention. (Really your only hope is to rely on people sorting by "active", or extremely dedicated voters intent on reading _every_ available answer.)

Comment: @Ajedi32 I find this doesn't tend to matter in practice. Most "questions" with multiple pages of answers either already have the needed info centralized near the top or are Meta questions where it's more important for SO staff to see the answer (which they will since they wrote the "question").

Comment: _Focus on quality if you want your answers to get attention_ I agree with @Ajedi32 I have seen many other really good quality answers got unnoticed just because they were answered later or were on page 3 or 4. The feature set, proposal and feedback seeking posts are bound by timelines and _sometimes it takes time_ can expire the validity of the feedback.

Comment: @KaranDesai If the feedback is useless later simply because time passes, then it wasn't great feedback.

Comment: I didn't mean that feedback is "useless" what I quoted was that even useful and high quality feedback remains unnoticed or gets noticed too late.

Comment: Reputation, points, votes, badges, etc. are a key element of Stack Exchange sites.  Much of meta discussion, blog posts and continual improvements to the site are all about visibility and addressing these type of issues. Just as you find the question "inherently reprehensible", I find dismissal of these types of questions as inherently ignorant of not only how SO works, but of how it's evolved. Letting "the chips fall where there(sic) may" is the antithesis of quality development. Why focus on quality of the questions if the website is just left as stagnant code because it works well enough!?

Comment: @jpmc26 And how do you determine that "Most questions... already have the needed info centralized near the top..."?  Even if that's your experience with the questions you view, there are apparently others that both read and answers questions where this does not happen... where old, original answers remain on top while better late answers remain "hidden".  Personal assumptions and individual experience are not sufficient reason for dismissing an entire question with negative answers and derogatory comments.

Comment: @CPerkins They are key elements that work best when they are obtained naturally, without artificial intervention to influence the behavior of others. Prioritizing your fake internet points above creating quality content only makes them less functional. As for how SO has "evolved," SO has changed much for the worse, losing its focus on quality and good work in favor of trying to attract as many users as possible. Additionally, I see no evidence of content stagnating. Questions with large numbers of answers have them because the problems in them are common and receive a lot of attention.